# Mapping Lambda output to API Gateway header

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to map the JSON output from a Lambda function to the header of an API Gateway call. As an example here, we can consider a redirect scenario. So I'd like to add a `Location` header to the response from my API Gateway call.

JSON output from Lambda function:

```
{
    Location: 'http://google.com'
}
```

In "Method Response"->"Response Headers" I can add the `Location` header to the desired HTTP status code.

Then in "Integration Response"->"Header Mappings" I can add the mapping for the `Location` header to be **something**.

Now my question is what should this **something** be?

Note: I've tried `integration.response.header.Location`, or using "Mapping Templates" but no luck so far.

There's a chance that it might not be possible at the moment (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=651482), but since API Gateway/Lambda are evolving so quickly at the moment I'll ask anyway.

Comment: `Map the output from your Lambda function to the headers and output model of the 200 method response.` This statement from the Integration response screen in API Gateway makes it look like it should be possible. But unable to find out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the AWS developer forums today (25 September 2015) this isn't possible yet, but may be coming in the future:

> API Gateway does not currently support mapping from the integration response body to the response headers, but we are looking to add support for this in the future.

[Forum post here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=676533)

**Edit December 2015**: Feature as been added according to a post by an AWS employee in the thread linked above. Thanks to [Peter Fox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/795290/peter-fox) for pointing that out.

Answer (score 10):

As of today (January 2016), it works by simply specifying `integration.response.body.Location` in your case.

Answer (score 5):

Today (12th, November, 2015), I was looking for how to pass the Location header from my backend API to a Location header in integration response.

This configuration worked and I could get Location header from backend api:

[image]

Looks like the solution proposed by Tobias is possible currently. However, the Location header points to the backend API and this is not what we want. I'll try to find a solution for this and post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it seems you can access to all the headers provided by the original response (if it contains a **Content-type**, then you can type : **integration.response.header.Content-type**). However, I have not find out any way to add a new header (except statically).

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while since this was asked but you can now set:

**integration.response.header.Location** (note Uppercase L in Location) in Mapping value if you are setting it in response headers.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jForq.png)